# Badge Suggestion: Voting for answers that are competing closely with your own

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

We have the silver [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge available for users who have "up voted 100 competing answers".

I propose a related badge for upvoting a competing answer when your vote is more likely to affect which one will end up in the lead, and be accepted.

> #### [More Sportsmanlike] Badge
>
> *Silver*
>
> Up-vote 30 competing answers whose scores are within two points of your own answers, before an answer has been accepted.

Comment: I revoke my suggestion, but I can't delete it! Stop downvoting me! D=

Comment: converted to wiki to protect your rep :) badge seems a bit too complex for my liking

Answer (score 5):

In the niche tags most all scores are within two of your answer.

It would make more sense to have a Gold badge with a higher count needed, like 500 or so.